# Do I need to submit pluginsRepo to the aragon repository or can I use any custom developed plugin from a personal reporegistry contract?

Tags: dao, repositories, registries

I want to create my own plugin for the aragonOSx framework, but I'm unsure whether I need to submit my plugin into Aragon's `pluginRepo` or if I can use a developed plugin from a personal `repoRegistry` contract?

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own custom plugin!

Here's how: https://devs.aragon.org/docs/core/how-to-guides/plugin-development/implemention/

TLDR:

1. you'll want to build your `Plugin` contract, which contains the logic of your plugin + build a `PluginSetup` contract which contains all the instructions regarding installing, uninstalling, updating a plugin for a DAO.
2. then, you want to use the `createPluginRepoWithFirstVersion` function from the `PluginRepoFactory.sol` contract and pass it the address of your `PluginSetup.sol` contract. And you're done - your plugin will be published in the aragonOSx protocol for anyone to use!!

Here's an example of an Aragon `Multisig` plugin:

- Code: https://github.com/aragon/core/tree/develop/packages/contracts/contracts/voting/multisig
- Published plugin on Etherscan: https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x2F41BD1405E066749FFC719468ac8920BA815be1

For some additional context on publishing:

The way it works is the `PluginSetup` contract holds a connection to your `Plugin` contract and any other `Helper` contracts. It is the one who sets the permissions for everything to work and presents the instructions on how to install this version of your `Plugin` in your DAO.
So, what you're doing when you call on the `createPluginRepoWithFirstVersion` from the `PluginRepoFactory.sol` contract is that you're generating a `PluginRepo` for your plugin with this specific `PluginSetup` as your first version. That way, when you want to update your plugin, you can simply update the version in your `PluginRepo` contract and submit a new `PluginSetup` contract.
The `PluginRepo` is your homebase for all versions of a given plugin and is an array filled with previous `PluginSetup` contract addresses from previous versions.

For additional context if needed:

1. Here is the `createPluginRepoWithFirstVersion` from the `PluginRepoFactory` - which creates the first version of a plugin and adds it to the `PluginRepoRegistry`: https://github.com/aragon/core/blob/develop/packages/contracts/src/framework/plugin/repo/PluginRepoFactory.sol#L48
2. This is how the `PluginRepoFactory` knows the `PluginRepoRegistry`: https://github.com/aragon/core/blob/da1278afd8263f7cc13973853bd3b58a352a1ec8/packages/contracts/src/framework/plugin/repo/PluginRepoFactory.sol#L15
3. Once the `PluginRepo` with the initial version in it is created, subsequent versions are released through the `PluginRepo` contract for that plugin, which is registered in the `PluginRepoRegistry` after you call on the `createPluginRepoWithFirstVersion`: https://github.com/aragon/core/blob/da1278afd8263f7cc13973853bd3b58a352a1ec8/packages/contracts/src/framework/plugin/repo/PluginRepo.sol#L134