# Should I create my aragonOSx plugin manually or through the aragon SDK?

Tags: solidity, protocol, smart-contract

It is unclear to me whether I should build a plugin using the [Aragon SDK](https://github.com/aragon/sdk) or if I should build my own smart contracts plugin manually and publish it to the [aragonOSx protocol](https://github.com/aragon/core)?

Answer (score 0):

The SDK's current focus is in providing browser clients to interact with the DAO and with any plugins it may have installed. In future iterations, we may provide tools to ease the plugin publication process.

However, as of right now, plugins are built entirely using Solidity. Answer on how to do that is here: [Do I need to submit pluginsRepo to the aragon repository or can I use any custom developed plugin from a personal reporegistry contract?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/144027/do-i-need-to-submit-pluginsrepo-to-the-aragon-repository-or-can-i-use-any-custom/144028#144028)

**TLDR:** every plugin consists of a `Plugin.sol` contract containing the plugin logic and a `PluginSetup.sol` contract containing the plugin installation instructions.

Then, in order to publish, you want to call the `createPluginRepoWithFirstVersion` function from the `PluginRepoFactory.sol` contract and pass it the address of your `PluginSetup.sol` contract. After that, you're done and your plugin is published for any Aragon DAO to use!